# Client validate jquery plugin doesn't work

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

I use for client validation the jquery plugin on the path assets\javascripts\jquery.validate.js (rails 3.2). But it doesn't work. My form:

update_name_phone_city_user_registration_path,
      :html => { :id => "form_edit_name", :method => :put }, :remote => true) do |f| %>

            
            
            
            
            
             10 %> 

       "submit" %>

My application.js file:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap-modal
//= require_tree .


$(document).ready(function() {

$("#form_edit_name").validate({
   debug: true,
   rules: {
      "user[name]": {
        required: true,
        minlength: 2
      },
    "user[name]": {
      required: 'Your username is required',
      minlength: 'The minimum number of characters is 2'
     }

     alert("ok");
   });

});
```

What's wrong?

UPD 1 The generated HTML- code

```
<script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-modal.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.validate.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>


<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/users" class="edit_user" id="form_edit_name" method="post">
<div><label for="user_name">Name</label><br />
        <input id="user_name" name="user[name]" size="30" type="text" value="" /></div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you are validating a test input like this

```
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" />
```

try this

```
$("#form_edit_name").validate({
       debug: true,
       rules: {
          "name": { required: true, minlength: 2 },
       messages: {
        "name": {
          required: 'Your username is required',
          minlength: 'The minimum number of characters is 2'
         }
      }
    });
```

Comment: @Stack Stack what does your html look like?

Comment: I doubt having a name with square brackets in will work with jquery.

Comment: I think, problem in modal window.

Comment: I loaded my form in modal via ajax. After removing form out of modal window, all works.

Answer (score 0):

The solution seems to be placing the name value in the quotes.

```
$("#form_edit_name").validate({
   debug: true,
   rules: {
      "user[name]": { required: true, minlength: 2 },
   messages: {
      "user[name]": {
       required: 'Your username is required',
       minlength: 'The minimum number of characters is 2'
     }
  }
});
```

See
[jQuery Validator Plugin on Ruby on Rails 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7183881/jquery-validator-plugin-on-ruby-on-rails-3) for details.